# Different render results if I render with CPU vs GPU

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This morning I received a new computer with a NVIDIA graphic card and I wanted to test it with an animation that my previous computer couldn't handle.
But I'm having some problems with the lighting of the scene. Here are some pictures of what's is going on:
Viewport with CPU rendering:[image]

Viewport with GPU rendering:
[image]

Thank you very much!!

Comment: please add blend file

Comment: Sorry I'm new in Stack Exchange and I still have a lot to learn. How can I upload a file? Also, I think that is around 150 MB... maybe I should upload it compressed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is weird, usually GPU fails, CPU render doesn't use environment light ... to share file use https://blend-exchange.com copy paste given code into your Q via edit. Don't upload 150 MB, simplify your file you can delete all objects and material (also check in Outliner > Orphan Data and delete all that left there) of course if issue still persists.

Comment: How to upload: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: @Chris ... Thanks for the link ... The script seems to be awesome !

Comment: Thanks for the link. I solved the problem, when I moved the file from one computer to the other one there was a problem with the textures. But now I know how to upload files to stack exchange. Thanks